# How we can search structures recursively for a variable value under windbg using script

Tags: scripting, windbg

can we write a script searching for a particular value under structures recursively? 
One manually way (and time taking) I can think of is to create a log file with the "dt -r " and searching it manually.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by searching for a value recursively ?

dt -r follows structures within structures and as such their Address will not be contiguous

you can use a the simple **s command** t osearch within a limited space like this

```
kd> r? $t0 = sizeof(nt!_EPROCESS)
kd> ? @$t0
Evaluate expression: 704 = 000002c0

kd> r? $t1 =  @@masm(@$proc)
kd> ? @$t1
Evaluate expression: -2063606960 = 84ffdb50


kd> $$ @$proc is pointer to current process in kernel mode
let us search for char 'k' within this range

kd> s -b @$t1 l?@$t0 'k'

84ffdcbc  6b 64 2e 65 78 65 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02  kd.exe..........

kd> dt nt!_EPROCESS ImageFileName @$proc
   +0x16c ImageFileName : [15]  "kd.exe"

kd> ? @$t1+0x16c
Evaluate expression: -2063606596 = 84ffdcbc
kd>
```